# Boostrap css file overrode my css file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, stylesheet

I included bootstrap to my site to use for some additions, but the bootstrap css file overrode some of my css styling in my css file. Is there a way to make it to where I can use bootstrap css without having it override stylings I have already done?

Thanks for your time, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: post some HTML and the relevant css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to link the css files in the correct order on the web page. If you link the bootstrap file first then the custom css file it will override the bootstrap file.

Comment: css specificity also plays a role here

Answer (score 1):

It is by the order of the files, you must first load the Bootstrap CSS and just below yours. Something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/mycustom.css" />
```

That should solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

add a !important to the elements within your css style sheet that you do not want to be changed.

example

```
myElement{
background-color: #ffff00 !important;
}
```